# Mi tecla de tab empezó a dar 8 espacios en lugar de 4

Tags: teclado, hardware

Estaba programando y me di cuenta que me tecla de Tab comenzó a dar una tabulación de 8 espacios en lugar de 4. He estado probando esto en otros programas (para descartar que fuera por mi IDE) y me di cuenta que el problema está en la configuración de mi teclado.

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo reestablecer o cambiar esto? (Mi sistema operativo es windows 10)

Comment: Si este problema se da en todos los programas, si es problema del teclado; sin embargo, si se da en uno solo puede que el editorconfig se haya desconfigurado. Si usas VS Code, localiza la barra de la parte inferior y asegúrate que diga Spaces: 4 si no dice eso, puedes configurarlo dando click a ese botón.

Comment: El problema se me esta dando en todos los programas, pero no sé por qué. Esto sucedió de un momento a otro

Comment: Por descarte ¿Si intentas tabular con otro teclado el problema persiste?

Comment: Acabo de cambiarlo y el problema aún sigue. No sé si haya forma de configurarlo de nuevo

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no trata sobre programación, tal como lo establece el [help/on-topic]. Es un problema de hardware o de configuración de software que no se puede reproducir.